# Move universal windows app 8.1 from Visual Studio 2013 to Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I had an universal application 8.1 that built fine on VS2013 Professional. Then I upgrade VS2013 to VS2015 Community. Now I had lot of errors like

```
Error   CS0115  'App.Configure()': no suitable method found to override MMCClient.WindowsPhone  D:\Projects\NewMMC_WP_Client.Shared\App.xaml.cs 64
```

If I add new universal application v8.1 project to that solution it built good.

Can sombody help me figure out that problem?

Comment: Have you installed the Windows Phone 8 devleopment parts of VS2015?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Yes. If I haven't it was impossible to add new uwp project to the solution

Comment: There is no such thing as UWP 8.1. The Universal Windows Platform was introduced in Windows 10. Visual Studio has support for UWP apps as of Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find any solution for my problem.

So I uninstall all development stuff (visual studio, emulators, sdk and other) and reinstall VS2015 Community + WP 8.1 SDK. And now my project builds fine.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have these options:

**Option 1**: Migrate Store/Phone 8.1 apps to a UWP solution in VS2015. A UWP soln will still provide you with 8.1 compatibility

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt148501.aspx

**Option 2**: Migrate the same project from VS2013 to VS2015 via dummy project

- http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/migrate-to-vs2015/

*p.s. you should probably provide additional proj/sln information/configuration*